# How to convert grayscale values in matrix to an image in Python?

Tags: python, image, grayscale

I have a set of grayscale values in matrix of shape 24x24:

```
masked=[[149 172 160 166 170 179 180 176 202 190 221 232 125 112 153 132 200 185
  191 231 227 101  85 127] ...
```

And I try to save this matrix file to a grayscale image as follows:

```
im = Image.fromarray(masked_crop)
im.save('crop.png')
```

But instead of having those values in my image, I get a complete dark image of size 24x24. 
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you put your matrix online somewhere (e.g. in a gist) so we can easily try it for ourselves?

Comment: I have tried to write the output to the file but the file which was written had non-unicode text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display and save an image with matplotlib

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = numpy.random.rand(10, 10)*255
plt.imshow(x, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.savefig('text.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Again thanks. It worked. What is the purpose of using Interpolation?

Comment: Actually, with interpolation='nearest' you deactivate the default interpolation. Maybe just have a look at the picture without the interpolation option ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `fromarray` has no docstring, but what you are trying should work if your "matrix" is a `numpy` array (or otherwise implements the array interface) and you additionally set the mode to 'L' (as the second argument to `fromarray`).